# Decryption Works and Encryption Does not

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, encryption, cryptography

I have converted an old project(crap, 0 documentation) from asp.net 1.1 to 4.5 ,which works fine.But now we have to change the connection strings of a project that interacts with ours so it points to our new sql database. And we need to encrypt the new sqlconnection strings but there was 0 documentation on this and how they encrypt the strings

I have managed to get the decryptor working:

```
public static string DecryptConnectionString(string value)
        {
            string cryptoKey = "xxxxxxxx";
            Byte[] IV = { xxx, x, xx, xx, x, xx,xxx,xx};
            Byte[] byt;
            byt = Convert.FromBase64String(value);

            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider des = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();

            MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            des.Key = md5.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cryptoKey));
            des.IV = IV;

            return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(des.CreateDecryptor().TransformFinalBlock(byt, 0, byt.Length));

        }
```

But my encryptor isn't working it gives me a bogus string of random characters (like a club) and when i plug back into the decryptor it crashes

Here is my encryptor work so far:

```
 public static string EncryptConnectionString(string value)
        {
            char[] v =value.ToCharArray();
            string cryptoKey = "xxxxxxxxx";
            Byte[] IV = { xxx, x, xx, xx, x, xx,xxx,xx};
            Byte[] byt;
             byt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value);



            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider des = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();

            MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            des.Key = md5.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cryptoKey));
            des.IV = IV;


            return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(des.CreateEncryptor().TransformFinalBlock(byt, 0, byt.Length));
        }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make an encryptor out of a working decryptor (or vice versa), you can reverse the process step-by-step:

```
byt = Convert.FromBase64String(value);

TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider des = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();

MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
des.Key = md5.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cryptoKey));
des.IV = IV;

return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(des.CreateDecryptor().TransformFinalBlock(byt, 0, byt.Length));
```

Taking out the parts related to key-making, and separating function calls:

```
TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider des = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
des.Key = md5.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cryptoKey));
des.IV = IV;

byt = Convert.FromBase64String(value);
byte[] decrypted  = des.CreateDecryptor().TransformFinalBlock(byt, 0, byt.Length)
return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(decrypted);
```

Then reverse the operations in their order:

```
// here lies the key-making code

return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(decrypted);
byte[] decrypted  = des.CreateDecryptor().TransformFinalBlock(byt, 0, byt.Length)
byt = Convert.FromBase64String(value);
```

And finally reverse each one in actual operation (input becomes output, decrypt becomes encrypt, etc):

```
// here lies the key-making code

byt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value);
byte[] encrypted = des.CreateEncryptor().TransformFinalBlock(byt, 0, byt.Length)
return Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);
```

Answer (score 5):

This is problematic:

```
return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(...);
```

The result of encryption is arbitrary binary data. Do *not* try to convert it into a string like that - you'll almost always lose data.

Instead, either just return the encrypted data as a `byte[]`, or use something like Base64 to convert it into text in a reversible way:

```
return Convert.ToBase64String(...);
```

In fact, in your *decryption* code you already appear to be assuming it's Base64:

```
byt = Convert.FromBase64String(value);
```

... so you don't even need to change the decryption code.

(I'm pretty dubious about using MD5 to create a key like this, by the way - but that's a different matter. Oh, and currently you can't handle any non-ASCII text (use UTF-8 instead) and you call `ToCharArray` for no obvious reason.)

See my [blog post on reversible data transformations](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/01/20/diagnosing-issues-with-reversible-data-transformations/) for more details about this sort of thing, and how to take the process apart step-by-step if you run into a similar problem in the future.

Comment: I typed the the answer then saw your blog post and now I'm embarrassed!